# How can I write Parsed JSON to a CSV fie?

Tags: python, json, api, csv, parsing

**Note**: Please see comments of ticked answer for resolution :)

I'm writing some python which accesses an API and the exports the server's response (JSON) to a CSV file. The JSON is nested.

This is the JSON response from the server (this is just a sample of the response):

```
{  
   "id":182774,
   "website_id":307842,
   "engine_provider":"Google",
   "engine_name":"United Kingdom",
   "keywords":[  
      {  
         "id":4464443,
         "groups_id":[  
            44424
         ],
         "name":"SMART E70 Interactive Display",
         "positions":{  
            "2017-03-16":10
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":4464442,
         "groups_id":[  
            44424
         ],
         "name":"SMART Podium SP518",
         "positions":{  
            "2017-03-16":4
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":4464441,
         "groups_id":[  
            44424
         ],
         "name":"SMART Board M680",
         "positions":{  
            "2017-03-16":3
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":4464338,
         "groups_id":[  
            51168
         ],
         "name":"NEC Lamps",
         "positions":{  
            "2017-03-16":4
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

If the JSON is looking wrong, it's probably because I edited it wrong when sampling it for this post.

In Python I try to parse the query response and then write the nested fields to a CSV table like this:

```
parsedqueryresponse = queryresponse.json()
f = csv.writer(open(csvoutputpath, "wb+"))
f.writerow(["name", "positions", "id"])
for parsedqueryresponse in parsedqueryresponse:
    f.writerow([parsedqueryresponse["keywords"]["name"],
               parsedqueryresponse["keywords"]["positions"],
               parsedqueryresponse["keywords"]["id"]])
```

When I run the script I get this error:

"*line 146, in 
    f.writerow([parsedqueryresponse["keywords"]["name"],
TypeError: string indices must be integers*"

Line 146 is this one (also referenced by the error message):

```
f.writerow([parsedqueryresponse["keywords"]["name"]
```

**What am I doing wrong here**? I tried changing the JSON fields to use ' instead of " but that didn't seem to make things any better...

Comment: probably 'parsedqueryresponse' is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
import csv
import json

parsedqueryresponse = queryresponse.json()
f = csv.writer(open(csvoutputpath, "wb+"))
f.writerow(["name", "positions", "id"])
for entry in parsedqueryresponse["keywords"]:
    f.writerow([entry["name"],
               entry["positions"],
               entry["id"]])
```

**Output:**

```
name,positions,id
SMART E70 Interactive Display,{2017-03-16: 10},4464443
SMART Podium SP518,{2017-03-16: 4},4464442
SMART Board M680,{2017-03-16: 3},4464441
NEC Lamps,{2017-03-16: 4},4464338
```

Please let me know in terns of any queries.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!

Now I just get this:

" line 142, in <module>
    parsedqueryresponse = json.loads(queryresponse.json())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer"

Comment: it means 'queryresponse.json()' is not a string. please find the type of 'queryresponse.json()'

Comment: if the type is dict then you don't need to use json.loads()

Comment: When I re'wrote it like this as you instructed it worked perfectly :)

"parsedqueryresponse = queryresponse.json()
f = csv.writer(open(csvoutputpath, "wb+"))
f.writerow(["name", "positions", "id"])
for entry in parsedqueryresponse["keywords"]:
    f.writerow([entry["name"],
               entry["positions"],
               entry["id"]])"

Comment: One thing I wonder though, what does ""wb+" actually do? I copied that from some example code. My code works, but I have no idea why that is there!

Comment: W means write. B means binary. + Means append. So it will append the input to the file in binary mode.